# Check if array has one or more empty keys than remove parent array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array (key - value), and some values are not set, empty in this case, if so the parent array must be removed from the main array.

The code that I have build only removes the empty key.

In my example the IT & ES language translation keys are empty so we need to removed this parent array.

```
$results = $arr =array(
    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [language] => de
                    [translation] => blog/beer
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [language] => en
                    [translation] => blog/some-slug-yeah
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [language] => es
                    [translation] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [language] => fr
                    [translation] => blog/paris-big-city
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [language] => it
                    [translation] =>
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [language] => nl
                    [translation] => blog/nederlands-slug
                )

        )

        [...]//more
)
```

Function to remove keys.

```
        function array_filter_recursive($input){
            foreach ($input as &$value){
                if (is_array($value)){
                    $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
                }
            }
            return array_filter($input);
        }

        $results  = array_filter_recursive( $results );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array always has 2 levels, you don't need recursion.

```
 function array_filter_recursive($input){
        foreach ($input as &$value){
            $value = array_filter($value, function($x) { return !empty($x['translation']); });
        }
        return $input;
    }
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/944816)

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is always going to be like this:

```
$arr = (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [language] => de
                [translation] => blog/beer
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [language] => en
                [translation] => blog/some-slug-yeah
            )
```

you can do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++}
    if(!isset($arr[$i]["translation"]){
        unset($arr[$i])
    }
}

//re-index thee array;
$arr = array_values($arr);
```